# Exporting a GLB file with two scenes and two cameras

Tags: animation, export, camera, blenderkit

I have a Food can model that ive animated. ive created two scenes, landscape and portrait, and each view has their own animations. The problem is when i export it as a GLB file the only camera appearing in the file is the view im currently in.So i need to know how to fix that. Note: Ive selected the "Cameras" option in the export.

Thank you

[image]